# Sort by Year in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Stumbled into a problem using an IMDb dataset that I can't seem to figure out. The question asks to show only movies produced in 1995. The problem is that the year is listed with each movie title, ie: "Toy Story (1995)". How can you scrape the year from a string of text?

Here's the question:

> Create a table that contains the names of 1995 movies

We have one table: Movies: id, name.

Movies

```
id,name
1,Toy Story (1995)
2,Jumanji (1995)
3,Grumpier Old Men (1996)
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995)
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1998)
6,Heat (1995)
```

Any ideas on how you would break apart the string of text to sort by year?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `like`:

```
where name like '% (1995)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question conatins two question so i would do based on

> Any ideas on how you would break apart the string of text to sort by year?

You can use `SUBSTRING()` to sort the data :

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE('(', name)+1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the title, rather than content, of the question...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'(',-1) + 0;
+----+------------------------------------+
| id | name                               |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  1 | Toy Story (1995)                   |
|  2 | Jumanji (1995)                     |
|  4 | Waiting to Exhale (1995)           |
|  6 | Heat (1995)                        |
|  3 | Grumpier Old Men (1996)            |
|  5 | Father of the Bride Part II (1998) |
+----+------------------------------------+
```